# Is it possible to get a the text in JUnit in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, junit

I need to get a report on performance. I need the text from **Window View** JUnit (see area in black in picture below), but there doesn't appear to be a way to copy it from the GUI. Does eclipse save this somewhere, or can it be extracted somehow?

[image: Sorry, I have to obscure the text - company policy]

Ted

Comment: Do you need the performance of the tests themselves or are you trying to get the performance of the method under test? If it's the latter, you should use a framework designed for performance testing instead of JUnit.

Comment: Are you using maven?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the JUnit view, you can click the little dropdown next to the History Log icon and click Export.  This will export to XML format which you should be able to parse out the details you need from there.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can use external tool to generate Junit report and extract expected data. For example you can use de goal [surefire-report:report-only](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-surefire-report-plugin/report-only-mojo.html) with Maven or the [JunitReport](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/junitreport.html) task with Ant.